# What object are `\def\foo{{a,b}}`?

Tags: macros, structure

Some day in my life i've created a tikz object using some tips from random parts of the internet and i've discovered the following:

`\def\foo{{a,b}}`

I don't have any example with it, but i'm preety shure that this is the way. It works like a vector, but i can't find any information of that structure. I've made a macro in my work using `xparse` package and i really wanted to use it inside those definitions, but some brutal erros get in the way.

What object is that? Just that i can search for it. And also, if someone could, there is a way to define something like the following?

```
\def\foo{{a,b}}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mezzocommand}{m O{0}}{
    ${#1} + \foo[#2]$
}
```

So that `\mezzocommand{x}[1]` produce $x+b$? Sorry for the lackness of example, but i just need to know *how* to search for it.

Comment: `{a,b}` could be a `pgfmath` array, in which each element is separated by comma and the array is enclosed in a pair of braces. Note in `{a, b}` both `a` and `b` should be a `pgfmath` variable or zero-argument function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\def\foo{{a,b}}` is unrelated to tikz, and doesn't make an object, it is a primitive tex macro definition, and defines `\foo` to be a macro which expands to the 5 tokens `{` `a` `,` `b` `}`

It isn't clear what rule you are wanting to implement with

> `\mezzocommand{x}[1]` produce `$x+b$`?

I will take a guess that you want 1 to take the 2nd (0-based count) item from the list `a,b` ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% use an expl3 clist below\def\foo{{a,b}}

% only needed in old latex \usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn\l_list{a,b}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mezzocommand}{m O{0}}{
    $#1 + \clist_item:Nn\l_list{#2+1}$
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mezzocommand{x}[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked nicely with the example i had in work

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pgfmath` (included in `tikz`, of course). On the other hand, it's not really clear what you're after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mezzocommand}{m O{0}}{%
    ${#1} + \pgfmathparse{\foo[#2]}\pgfmathresult$%
}

\def\foo{{"a","b"}}

\begin{document}

\mezzocommand{x}

\mezzocommand{x}[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definepseudoarray}{mm}
 {
  \clist_new:c { l__mezzo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l__mezzo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _clist } { #2 }
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{O{0}}
   {
    \clist_item:cn { l__mezzo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _clist } { ##1 + 1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\mezzocommand}{m O{0}}{%
    $#1 + \foo[#2]$%
}

\definepseudoarray\foo{a,b}

\begin{document}

\mezzocommand{x}

\mezzocommand{x}[1]

\end{document}
```

The `\foo` command can be made expandable if you use a mandatory argument to it, instead of an optional one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definepseudoarray}{mm}
 {
  \clist_new:c { l__mezzo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l__mezzo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _clist } { #2 }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{#1}{m}
   {
    \clist_item:cn { l__mezzo_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _clist } { ##1 + 1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\mezzocommand}{m O{0}}{%
    $#1 + \foo{#2}$%
}

\definepseudoarray\foo{a,b}

\begin{document}

\mezzocommand{x}

\mezzocommand{x}[1]

\end{document}
```